# How do I go on about making an image scroll inside a scrollview's specific area?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to create a cropping tool like they have done in the contacts app photo selection. I have got the view and the circular layer done. The only issue is scrolling inside it. I need the image to be scrollable upto its edges.

In the picture below you can see how the image's top end is well above the circle. I am not able to scroll the image to go below so that the top edge is in line with the circle's top edge. The reason is I don't know what I am supposed to do, not in terms of code. I don't get how I can get it down, as in what properties to use for that. Now as the image is zoomed in more, the top edge of the image is moving farther away from the circle's top edge and once the image is zoomed in to a zooming scale 1, the top edge of the image reaches the top edge of the view and I can't scroll it to the circle's top edge. So can somebody please give me some pointers on how to achieve it?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will want to increase the scrollview content inset values, so essentially there is more distance between the scrollview's content edges and the actual value contained within the scrollview.

Comment: Alternatively, when you setup your image view inside your scrollview, you can set top/bottom/left/right constraints to the superview's margins.  Then you can change the layout constraints constants to increase or decrease how much the scrollview can move in any direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the content inset values did the trick. Basically I calculated the top and bottom edges for the scrollview content inset for portrait mode and left and right for landscape and set those as the contentinset values.

Also had to set contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to never so that any unneeded inset changes are avoided. It works now.

```
if screenHeight > screenWidth {
    let top = (view.bounds.height / 2.0) - (view.bounds.width / 2.0)
    scrollView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, 0, top, 0)
} else {
    let top = (view.bounds.width / 2.0) - (view.bounds.height / 2.0)
    scrollView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, top, 0, top)
}
scrollView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```